# Expand $\frac{1-z}{1+z}$ into power series at a

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, power-series

Can someone please show how to expand $\frac{1-z}{1+z}$ into power series at a constant a?

I tried to expand separately $1-z$ and $1+z$ but I can't reduce them for the same constant a.

Comment: The question from the title is different from the question from the body. What is that you really want to know?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{1-z}{1+z}=\frac2{1+z}-1$$

so that the formula for the $n^{th}$ derivative is straightforward and you can use Taylor.

> $$\frac{1-a}{1+a}-\frac2{(1+a)^2}(z-a)+\frac2{(1+a)^3}(z-a)^2-\frac{2}{(1+a)^4}(z-a)^3-\cdots$$